# watermark ,crossing the Detail and Header sections in crystal reports

Tags: crystal-reports, watermark

I need to print watermark, which is crossing the Detail section and Header in crytal reports.

how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

- Insert a new Page Header section (PHb)
- Move it above the older one (it will now be PHa)
- Insert a picture
- Format new Page Header section (PHa), enable the "Underlay following section" property

You will probably need to adjust the positioning of the image in the PHa section and the size of the section.

Answer (score -4):

You can do this in Pentaho Report Designer
if you interested,see in sample reports provided by Pentaho Report Designer.